# Average and standard deviation pooling that ignores zero values, in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, max-pooling

I am trying to apply average, and standard deviation pooling, to each dimension across each vector in a batch, while ignoring any zero values.

Below is a minimum viable reproducible example of my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

av_pool = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda z: tf.math.reduce_mean(z, axis=1)
)

sd_pool = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda z: tf.math.reduce_std(z, axis=1, keepdims=False)
)

# Batch size = 2, sequence length = 4, vector size = 3
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    [[[1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1.], [1., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0.]], 
     [[1., 1., 1.], [0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0.]]],
    dtype=tf.float32
)

mask = tf.not_equal(a, tf.zeros_like(a))        

non_zero = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(a, mask)  

# average pooling works
averages = av_pool(non_zero)

# however standard deviation pooling does not
standard_deviations = sd_pool(non_zero)

# producing the following error:
# ValueError: keepdims=True is not supported for RaggedTensors.
```

Please may somebody help me understand what is going wrong? Why does the average pooling work while the standard deviation pooling does not?

Thank you.

Comment: your code runs correctly without any error

Comment: Must be my version of tensorflow - I am using version 2.2